# Number of ways to distribute 10 balls into 4 urns such that one urn has at-least 3 balls?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations, balls-in-bins

How many ways are of distributing 10 balls into 4 urns such that one urn has at-least 3 balls?

My basic approach is to choose 1 urn in which I am gonna place 3 balls before hand. I can choose i urn from 4 in 4 ways.

Now I need to distribute 7 balls into 4 urns. I solve this using bars and stars. So number of ways are 10C3.

So answer is 4+10C3.

What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: I'm confused about the question.  The way it is phrased, it seems you are looking for a method of distribution, to which I would say dump all ten balls in an earn so that now you have one urn with at least 3 balls...

Comment: Apparently you want to know the number of ways to distribute subject to the given stipulation. But you also need to specify whether balls/urns are labelled or unlabelled.

Comment: @Carser I have edited the title as well as question to remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible for up to $3$ urns to have $3$ balls simultaneously. These will be double counted in your scheme. Also, assuming that the approach were *not* giving double counting, you would need to multiply the successive choices, not add them.

Incidentally, the pigeonhole principle tells us that in any distribution of $10$ balls to $4$ urns, there will always be an urn with at least $3$ balls. [Stars & bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) gives the distribution of $10$ indistinguishable balls to $4$ distinct urns as ${13\choose 3}=286$.